# Adding new entry points to a python package through setup.cfg

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I packaged a collection of scripts and installed them through `pip install -e .` using a `setup.cfg` file.

Now, I would like to add some more entry points, i.e. to "update" the installation such that I can use the new entry points:

`setup.cfg`:

```
(...)

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    old_entry_point = file.cli:old_entry_point
    new_entry_point = file.cli:new_entry_point1
    (...)
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

I think I am looking for the equivalent of `python setup.py develop` for a the setup.cfg file.

Comment: Add the new entry points to `setup.cfg` then re-run the editable installation: `python -m pip install --editable .`.